# Square of sum of two I.I.D. random variables

Tags: probability

I have a simple question that I am unable to grasp, a little help with explanation will be highly appreciated.

Let's say we have two iid random variables $x$ and $y$, such that $E[x^Hx]=\sigma_x^2$ and $E[x^Hy]=0$ then how do we expand the simple square of these two variables, $|x+y|^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E((X+Y)^2) = E((X+Y)^H(X+Y)) = E(X^HX) + E(Y^HY) + E(X^HY) + E(Y^HX)$

Since, $X$ and $Y$ are iid, $E(X^HX) = E(Y^HY) = \sigma_x^2$ and $E(X^HY) = E(Y^HX) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks @expiTTp1z0

Comment: Just one more question; how do I solve this $$E[|X.Y|^2]$$